# What AVG Creep Score Per Game should a Jungler have?

Tags: league-of-legends

So as the title asks, what CS should a jungler have per game? What's the Diamond/Master/Challenger standard? Per game I'm getting around 100CS that is if all my laners always clear there lanes and take my jungle camps more often later on. If they don't I get around 200+ for a 30-40min game.

Comment: This is way too broad. It depends on **many** factors. From clearing speed to how many times you gank to how many objectives you got or protected.

Comment: But does it? Often no matter what champion no matter what game Challanger to Pro players will still get 150-200+ CS in a game, so that's why I'm asking whats the avg. There's a avg for all lanes, there must be one for jungle

Comment: There is an average for everything. That doesn't mean that it is always useful. You can have an average of 300 cs per game and 0 ganks, or 100 cs and 15 kills per game. Average here means nothing.

Comment: I can't see why this is so broad since the question was answered covering any broader opinions by covering lane tax etc. you guys just vote to shut down a question for the hell of it I've met with this community. You all follow these rules to stern. I asked yes a broad question which does have a definite answer which I received you guys need to chill out. Life isn't always about rules. The greatest people in history broke all the rules.

Comment: Asking which is the best dog breed can be answered by anyone, that doesn't make it less opinion based or broad. As for the rules, you can complain in [Arqade Meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That's a terrible comparison. Like I'm questioning do you even play league? Or aren't bronze, cause you have it in your head that there's isn't such thing as avg CS for jungle no matter what game. There is and I got the answer which makes sense. The comparison is terrible because of the fact that this question isn't as broad as you think. There is no such thing as the best dog breed. But there is a close to avg CS you should get per 10min as jungler

Comment: Did you read my comments? I said there *is* average. But it's as useful as the average of throwing a dice. Also, your attempts to insult me have no effect (btw i m d5 and i dont play that much nowadays). Arqade Meta awaits your complains.

Comment: @Charkz The average CS for a jungler doesn't matter.  It's the impact he's making on the actual game.  You might have a powerfarming jungler have 300CS by clearing camps super fast and then going into lanes and stealing CS.  You might have anther jungler only get a total of 50CS in a 50 minute game because they spend all their team putting pressure throughout the map.  Sure there is an average CS in the jungle but it literally means nothing.

Comment: Honestly, if you are getting 200CS as a jungler in a 30-40 minute game you are doing something wrong.  You are either spending too much time in the jungle or you are a dick stealing all of ur lanes gold/exp or both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Jutschge already answered, this depends on the type of jungler you're playing.

#### Farmjungler:

These Junglers will mainly try to farm until lategame, doing a small amount of ganks when the chances of success are high. Usually, they are played with the devourer enchantment. These are quite unpopular in the soloQ (AMUMU 4 GANKS YOU NONE NOOB), but are able to carry a game later on on their own.

Noteable examples: Warwick, Master Yi, Nocturne

#### Gankjungler:

These jungler have a slow clearspeed and because of that, they rely on ganking as their biggest source of gold income. These are usually champs with a lot of CC, good earlygame damage and/or and good gapclosers.

Noteable examples: Shaco, Wukong, Nautilus

#### Golden-Mid-Junglers:

Most of the junglers belong into this category. These are junglers with a decent clearspeed and a good ganking potential. You can either help out the lanes pretty good or - if they all push - you can farm to become a bigger threat later on.

Noteable examples: Vi, Xin, Rengar

How much CS you should have with a jungler depends on the impact you had in the game. If you gank a lot (I assume you don't tax), you will have a lower CS score, but the same or even more gold than the enemy jungler with more creeps. If you play a farmjungler, you should aim for 65 CS per 10 minutes. That's a solid value for a mid-tier player and will give you a good amount of stacks on your devourer too to have enough impact later on.

Answer (score 1):

This really depends on the jungler you're playing. Some junglers will focus mainly on ganking while others are constantly farming. There's also a difference between CS (Creep Score) and Jungle minions. A jungler that spends most of the time in his own or enemy jungle will have a lower number on the left but about the same gold as someone who is splitpushing often.

For junglers in general there isn't a standard CS. Game length, Team Strength and the flow of the game all have an impact on your final creep score.

If you are snowballing extremely hard you might aswell gank constantly and  neglect your farm in order to shut down the enemy team. Even if you are playing a champion that would usually farm.

[Champion.gg](http://champion.gg/statistics/#?roleSort=Jungle&sortBy=general.neutralMinionsKilledTeamJungle&order=descend) has a nice table about stats (creeps, own and enemy jungle minions) in platinum or higher games. But remember that this is the **average**.